# Why do I have only "id" part of xpath when I use "copy xpath?

Tags: python, selenium

[image: The form or input should be copied?]

When I copy the `xpath` I have the following: `//*[@id="submit"]`

Copy full XPath gives following results:`/html/body/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div/form/input`

How can I copy the full XPath? Or should I first copy XPath and then copy full XPath?

Many thanks

Comment: You can either use ```find_element(By.ID, "id")``` or use ```xpath``` as you want. I would suggest you write your own XPath instead of copying it. In your case the ```xpath``` would be ```//input[@id='submit']``` or ```//input[@value='Acceder al Procedimiento']```

Comment: Web scraping is a dark art. You need to decide which thing is most likely to remain constant even if the page itself changes over time. The XPATH is selecting  the exact full path to the input element but that is rather fragile. Any changes above the input could change the path. The id however, is more likely to be stable - that's why you have them in the first place. The `find_element` option is likely the fastest and most stable.